# Android msm8660 gralloc

Tags: android, logging

I am seeing this thing in the logcat over and over just wondering what is this about?

```
msm8660.gralloc(27909): gralloc_unlock hnd->base 0x47d81000, hnd->offset 0x0
```

This issue is reported various [places](http://code.google.com/p/bricked/issues/detail?id=45) and solved but nobody says why it is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msm8660 is Qualcomm's dual-core Snapdragon chipset.

gralloc is used to allocate graphics memory to app processes.

The message just seems to be informational in nature. It is reporting the unlocking of a chunk of memory that was previously locked for graphics usage.

I would not be concerned, logcat is usually filled with various logs from a myriad of processes.

Comment: Why it is printing as warning? is this a premature release ?  Just wondering if it could create crashes or screen freeze to video rendering apps.

Comment: I've been looking through libgralloc source code trying to find where this warning is originating from, but I've had no luck! Sorry I can't give you a more tangible answer right now. If you're still concerned, maybe bring it up on the XDA forums or the Qualcomm developer forums.